# Parser Combinators - Ordered Choice and Left-Recursion

Tags: scala

What is the significance of `ordered choice`? Does it simply mean that you put the longest pattern match first?

Let's say you had this expression"

```
val expr = "eat" ~ "more" ~ "beans" |
           "eat" ~ "more" ~ "beans" ~ "and" ~ "fruit"
```

Since parser combinators use `Ordered Choice`, the string `eat more beans and soup ...` would result in matching on the first line? The `val expr` uses `Ordered Choice` poorly since it includes a less-specific expression first?

Also, what is `left recursion`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala parser combinators implements parsing expression grammers. A PEG is predicated on the availability of infinite lookahead and backtracking capabilities which makes it easier to express grammars as it is not necessary to make a unilateral decision at any point in the parsing process.

Ordered choice/alternation can be considered the primary enabler of this behavior; a production under which a sequence of productions are tried in sequence, accepting the first one which matches the input. In your example above the second choice will never be matched because any input matching the second choice would be accepted by the first choice.

Left recursion occurs in the event that given a production of the form `a = b`, an expansion of `b` begins with `a`. Consider:

```
def a = b ~ c
def b = a ~ c
```

Expansion (matching) of the production `a` proceeds as follows:

```
b ~ c  
(a ~ c) ~ c             // substituting b
((b ~ c) ~ c) ~ c       // substituting a
(((a ~ c) ~ c) ~ c) ~ c // substituting b
```

This is effectively infinite, unterminated recursion.